# How to group two different spellings as one

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I am looking at rows of transportation data and I want to be able to manipulate the data for entries of 'Uber Pool' and 'UberPool' as the same mode of transit.

What can I do so that my functions aggregate all table entries of the two different spellings into one row in the output table?

Comment: A complex and sometimes language specific problem. Try upper/lower/soundex etc.

Comment: If the different spellings are known beforehand you can either use case expressions to treat different values as the same, or set up a mapping table if there are many different values. If you need it to be dynamic the problem gets a lot harder.

Comment: Define the rule by which two entries are considered equal. Is 'UberPool' = 'uBERpOOL'? Is 'Uber Pool' = 'U-b-e-r*P-o-o-l'? Is 'UberPool' = 'OoberPool'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jpw said, it depends on your data, but by the looks of it you can do it using `CASE EXPRESSION` in your  `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT CASE t.name = 'Uber Pool' then 'UberPool' else t.name end as name,count(*)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY CASE t.name = 'Uber Pool' then 'UberPool' else t.name end
```

You didn't tag your RDBMS, but in some of them you can specify the column alias from the select in the group by which will look better.

```
SELECT CASE t.name = 'Uber Pool' then 'UberPool' else t.name end as new_name,count(*)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY new_name
```

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You can remove spaces and standardize the case of the string, by doing something like this:

```
select min(t.name) as name, . . . 
from t
group by lower(replace(t.name, ' ', ''))
```

This retrieves one of the matching names as the first column.  You might find this easier to work with than listing a bunch of `case`s.